# How to add different color in bottom of the line

Tags: android, view, colors, line

i want create app like this:
http://psdmockups.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/android-design-mobile-app-gui-kit-psd-mockups-full.jpg
Then how to add different color in bottom of the line.

Comment: simple make an image and put imageview

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#111293" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#571293" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#571200" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#579993" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But I'm using Relative layout view

Comment: You can add linearLayout inside RelativeLayout on bottom.

Comment: One more Question Please look the 4.2 textview in below aligned How to create this.

Comment: But it will align right corner i want below right textview Andriod Ui Design kit PSD

Comment: So i'm using android:layout_marginRight="110dp" in textview 4.2. But I'm using device Landscape So it will

Comment: android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"

Comment: add warp_content to first textview

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
<RelativeLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#8D0D0D"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0D8D6F"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#388D0D"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#54dfac"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```